# How to make PHP read JSON?

Tags: php, json

I need PHP to read JSON from the server-side without need any client-side such as Javascript or Jquery. In other words, I want my script to return what it had read as HTML text something like what it could do with any other data source such as database or a text file.

Suppose that I have a PHP file at `http://example.com/sources/output.php` which output text in JSON format like the following:

```
{
"employees": [
  { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
  { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
  { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Then I have another PHP file at `http://example.com/readData.php`. I to know any way using just server-side PHP to make readData.php able to read `employees` and set them into an array.

Comment: If you Googled "php json" you would have found your answer quicker than it took you to write out your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://example.com/sources/output.php');
$parsedJson = json_decode($json);

$employees = $parsedJson->employees;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_decode($data, true)`. This will decode your JSON into an associative array. If the second parameter is not set (it's `false` by default), you'll get an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will natively decode and encode JSON (since version 5)

https://www.php.net/json_encode

https://www.php.net/json_decode

I'd output your JSON as a string `json_encode($object);` and then have your other script read it in like this `json_decode($_REQUEST['json']);`

I think that will work.